# Forwarding packets in a single Open vSwitch bridge

Tags: forwarding, openflow, switching, openvswitch

I am trying to emulate a L3-switch where multiple machines are connected (in no VLANs or a single VLAN.) Then I would like to configure the switch to forward packets as I want, which I had no luck.

#### My system configuration:

- Host machine OS: Ubuntu 18.04.
- Open vSwitch 2.9.0
- Client machines: UBuntu 18.04 clients in VirtualBox 5.2.20

#### What I want to do

(basically emulating a man-in-the-middle attack.)

1. VM1, VM2 and VM3 are connected to a virtual switch or bridge (BR0).
2. VM1 sends a packet (e.g., HTTP GET request) to VM3.
3. BR0 intercepts it and forward it to VM2.
4. VM2 sends the response to VM1.
5. BR0 forwards it to VM1 like VM3 responding.

#### What I did:

1. `ovs-vsctl add-br br0`: Create a bridge (BR0)
2. Create VM1,2,3 that use br0 as a network bridge.
3. Run different webservers inside VM2 and VM3 (e.g., VM2 returns "hello" at the root wheras VM3 returns "HELLO".)
4. Configure IP addresses inside each machine to, say,

   - VM1: 192.168.0.2
   - VM2: 192.168.0.3
   - VM3: 192.168.0.4
5. `ovs-ofctl --strict add-flow br0 priority=1,tcp,nw_dst=192.168.0.4,actions=mod_nw_dst=192.168.0.3`: Add a flow modifying the destintion IP. Catching packges going to VM3 and forwarding them to VM2 (I hope.)
6. `ovs-ofctl --strict add-flow br0 priority=1,tcp,nw_src=192.168.0.3,actions=mod_nw_src=192.168.0.4`: Add a flow modifying the source IP. To make the response come from VM3.

#### What I saw:

However, obviously, it was not successful.

- I can `ping` from one to another.
- I can `cURL` from one to another.
- However, the `mod_nw_dst` command was not effective. From VM1, I only can see the original response from VM3, which I wanted to forward to VM2.

I googled this a lot and found many articles about forwarding across VLANs, but not like this in a single bridge. Is my implementation incorrect? Otherwise, is it not an intended feature? In that case, what would be the best approach to emulate such things?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The result of `ovs-ofctl dump-flows br0` is just the above command.

`cookie=0x0, duration=157469.378s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=1,tcp,nw_src=192.168.0.3 actions=mod_nw_src:192.168.0.4
 cookie=0x0, duration=157462.433s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=1,tcp,nw_dst=192.168.0.4 actions=mod_nw_dst:192.168.0.3
 cookie=0x0, duration=157534.866s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=0 actions=NORMAL`

Comment: What's the full content of your OpenFlow tables (`ovs-ofctl dump-flows br0`)?

Comment: @pchaigno Hi, I just added the table in the text. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your second `ovs-ofctl add-flow` command wasn't taken into account. Did you get any error message when you ran that command?

Comment: @pchaigno Sorry, that I forgot to add that. I was playing with various configurations and the second command was redacted in the current setup. It didn't give me an error and showed the same result. I updated the table result above.

Comment: Did you empty the table before running these commands? There should be a default forwarding rule with a `NORMAL` action.

Comment: @pchaigno Yes, I think I cleared the table before. I will try to do it from scratch again. Do you think it caused a problem?

Comment: @pchaigno Hello Sir/Madam, I just reset the bridge and did the same, but the result remains the same. I updated ``dump-flows`` in the text as well. I'd appreciate if you could share any thoughts. Thanks!